# Automatically truncate string in LinqToSql?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

Is there an overall setting to automatically truncate my strings when working with LinqToSql?

I occasionally get the "`string or binary data would be truncated`" exception and it's OK for our solution to just trim off the excess.

As we have close to 100 entities each with a few dozen properties, I'm hoping there's something that I can implement system wide, rather than on a by-property basis.

Comment: @mellamokb - That was on a by-property basis.  Exactly what I'm looking to avoid.

Comment: Did you look at *all* the answers?  Also, the link I posted to codeproject may be more helpful.